# Is it possible to disable Snowflake users to view ANY metadata on other USERS or ROLES that exists?

Tags: security, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Even though it **is possible** to disable snowflake users from running `SHOW USERS` and only view their own query history, I am not able to and I even think it does not seem possible to:

- Disable users from running `SHOW ROLES` & disabling them from seeing the ROLES tab in the Snowsight UI
- Disable users from SEEING the full list of users when they use the users dropdown list in the query history tab.

Did anyone manage to accomplish this?
We need this functionality as we have the need to separate some users groups from each other / they should not know of their existence and we do not want to use the **organisations** feature to make this possible.
If this indeed is not possible we do see this as a *security risk* as someone having information about other users / roles potentially has more attack point info...

Answer (score 0):

If the user is assigned a custom role then the "Roles" tab will not be displayed when the user logs in to Snowflake UI.

For the 2nd point, it is currently not possible to hide the User's drop-down or limit it to the users who are in the same privilege level or under same roles as the logged-in user.

For eg:

```
create role customrole;

grant customrole to newuser;
```

Now, login as newuser and you will not be seeing the "Roles" Tab from the UI.

Edit: P.S on new UI this is expected behavior where in the Role tab is not hidden even if custom roles are assigned to user.It is something that the team is working to change.

Comment: Hi @Srinath, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it is unclear to me what you mean with 'assigned a custom role', as all the users I mean DO have one or more custom roles assigned (and also a default role). The role assigned IS part of a hierarchical role structure though...

Comment: Edited my answer and added the customrole part details.

Comment: Hi @srinath, we actually did that, all users have a custom role granted for a subset of users but the issue might be that these custom roles INHERIT aspects from a central 'all users' role. Or do you mean that we should create a dummy customrole for each users, grant that user that role and that that would remove the problem?
Or is the issue that as soon as a user has more then one role to choose from, that that will display the ROLES tab?

Comment: By any chance are you testing this from Classic UI or new UI (snowsight)?

Comment: We experience that problem in the new UI (snowsight). We preferably want those users to not be able to see the whole ACCOUNT tab at all...

Comment: Ok , that makes sense now why the Roles tab is still visible. For new UI this is expected behavior and at present, it is not hidden for users with any roles.

Comment: Ok, but for us it is unwanted behavior as it will give users a way to view all roles, their hierarchy and worse, all usernames. For us this is a privacy concern! I do hope this can be changed!